# SQL error creating table. Wrong syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    Nr INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Datum TIMESTAMP,
    Name VARCHAR(20), 
    Mymoney DOUBLE(20,10),
    mypercentage DOUBLE(25,20),
    Modifikation INT(10) UNSIGNED,
)
```

I get the error: Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8 ?>

Another 'SQL-statement checking' website gives me this error:
Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "UNSIGNED": syntax error)

please help!!!

Comment: This error is caused by a trailing comma after the last declaration. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the comma at the end of the last column definition.  Then, if you want to specify scale and precision, use `DECIMAL`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    Nr INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Datum TIMESTAMP,
    Name VARCHAR(20), 
    Mymoney DECIMAL(20,10),
    mypercentage DECIMAL(25,20),
    Modifikation INT(10) UNSIGNED
)
```

You can use scale and precision with `DOUBLE PRECISION`, but for monetary values, you should use fixed point representation.  For the "percentage" this is not so important:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    Nr INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Datum TIMESTAMP,
    Name VARCHAR(20), 
    Mymoney DECIMAL(20,10),
    mypercentage DOUBLE PRECISION,
    Modifikation INT(10) UNSIGNED
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove , from last column for fixing the query error.

Here is correct syntax of query

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    Nr INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Datum TIMESTAMP,
    Name VARCHAR(20), 
    Mymoney DOUBLE(20,10),
    mypercentage DOUBLE(25,20),
    Modifikation INT(10) UNSIGNED
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all because of the comma before the ')'

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
    CREATE TABLE my_table (
    Nr INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Datum TIMESTAMP,
    Name VARCHAR(20), 
    Mymoney DOUBLE(20,10),
    mypercentage DOUBLE(25,20),
    Modifikation INT(10) UNSIGNED
    );
```